# bash curl post request set timeout

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl

I make a post request from url like this

```
curl -s -X  POST http://site.com -d "data:data"
```

The thing is that I want to set a timeout for the url I am sending the post request to.

I tried `-m 5`, but then it doesn't make the request at all.

Comment: Just to be sure: The way you format your command in the example suggests you have tried adding the `-m 5` between -X and POST (`-X -m 5 POST`). It needs to be -X POST because POST is the argument to -X. Have you tried `curl -s -m 5 -X  POST http://site.com -d "data:data"`?

Comment: @Johan please add it as an answer so I can accept. It works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Haha, thanks :) (Wild guess comment to answer conversion below)*

Just to be sure: The way you format your command in the example suggests you have tried adding the `-m 5` between `-X` and `POST` (`-X -m 5 POST`). It needs to be `-X POST` because `POST` is the argument to `-X`. Have you tried `curl -s -m 5 -X POST http://site.com -d "data:data"`?